# Django urls are not return int, only simplelazyobject as kwargs even when specified

Tags: python, django

It is my understanding from the documentation, that when using "int:" in a path in a Django URL, it should send an int to my view in the kwargs. It is sending a simplelazyobject.

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import IndexView
urlpatterns = [
    path('invoices/<int:current_page>/', IndexView.as_view(), name='indexpaged')
]
```

my views.py

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_page = kwargs.get('current_page', 1)
        print(type(current_page))
```

output:

```
<class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>
```

Shouldn't the type be int? If I am misunderstanding the `<int:current_page>` returning an int, what is the best way to convert from that simplelazyobject to an int? I'm currently using: `current_page = int(str(current_page))` to work around it, and this does not seem like it would be the best process.

Thanks!

Comment: Using python 3.8 and django 3.2

Comment: Ehh.. `Django==3.2` has not been released yet. Check your version *again* and show some more details of your issue. Where it is happening, where are you accessing the `kwargs` etc.

Comment: I am using Django 3.2 alpha according to the output of: 
`django.VERSION`
`(3, 2, 0, 'alpha', 0)`

I've added more details to the original question.

Comment: that strange. I don't see any [Django==3.2](https://pypi.org/project/Django/#history) in PyPI. How did you install the 3.2?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember the exact install process. It's been a little bit. I get this when I run pip freeze
 `-e git+https://github.com/django/django.git@437196da9a386bd4cc62b0ce3f2de4aba468613d#egg=Django`. To eliminate this from being a possible issue, I've uninstalled that version and installed 3.0.8. and it has solved my problem. Thank you for noticing my Django version. Your comments have solved my issue. If you want to leave an answer below to this, I'll give it the big green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, I was using an early alpha release of Django and did not realize it. Thank you to Arakkal Abu for recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be fixed bt replacing `kwargs` with `self.kwargs`. Like this :

```
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_page = self.kwargs.get('current_page', 1)
        print(type(current_page))
```

source & detail explanation: [here](https://w.aaronoellis.com/articles/fixing-simplelazyobject-errors-in-django-3-1)

Comment: There are other answers and a accepted and written one from the OP himself, When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can just pass `current_page` as argument to the IndexView and access it as a int. No conversions are required this way:

```
def IndexView(request, current_page):
    print(current_page)
```